# How the trigger the Jenkins Job through the URL

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to jenkins.I have created a job in Jenkins UI using build with parameter plugin. I need to hit the below mentioned url so that the job need to triggered automatically with the parameter passed.

```
10.251.70.200:8080/job/trigger/build?Tag=123
```

But when I hit the above URL, the job page is displayed and parameter is not set as an argument to Jenkin job. Please guide me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger a build with an HTTP GET, you need to POST some data.  For a parameterized build you will need something like this:

```
json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"Tag\", \"value\": \"123\"}], \"\": \"\"}"
url=http://10.251.70.200:8080/job/trigger/build

curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json"
```

See the [Jenkins REST API documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) for more details.

Comment: how to pass json to jenkins??? is there anything need to configure in Jenkin UI ??

Comment: The curl command in the last line of my reply is how you pass the JSON data to Jenkins.  I'm assuming you have access to a Mac or Linux system where the curl command is native; if you're on Windows, see http://lebgeeks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=9377 for how to install a Windows version.

Comment: sorry for asking many doubts.Im using MAC.Where do i need to pass the thing which you provided.                                   json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"Tag\", \"value\": \"123\"}], \"\": \"\"}"
url=http://10.251.70.200:8080/job/trigger/build

curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json"

Comment: when i created a shell script <br>    json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"Tag\", \"value\": \"123\"}], \"\": \"\"}"
url=http://10.251.70.200:8080/job/trigger/build

curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json" <br> It thows an error    <html><head><title>Error 404</title></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1>Status Code: 404</h1>Exception: <br>Stacktrace: <pre>(none)
</pre><br><hr size="1" width="90%"><i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Thu Jan 23 11:24:10 GMT+05:30 2014</i></body></html>

Comment: added http but throwing error :                                         <html><head><title>Error 404</title></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1>Status Code: 404</h1>Exception: <br>Stacktrace: <pre>(none)
</pre><br><hr size="1" width="90%"><i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Fri Jan 24 16:24:54 GMT+05:30 2014</i></body></html>

Comment: need your help to fix this issue

Comment: Can you try an HTTP GET to verify your URL will build with the default parameters ?  It should be "curl http://10.251.70.200:8080/job/trigger/build".  If your Jenkins has security set up you may also need to add a token parameter - see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security and put "?token=TOKEN_VALUE" on the end of the URL if so.  If you don't have security enabled you can leave out the "-d token=zorn" in the PUT command above.

Comment: when i gave curl 10.251.74.56:8080/job/trigger/build , it thows the same error "<html><head><title>Error 404</title></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1>Status Code: 404</h1>Exception: <br>Stacktrace: <pre>(none)
</pre><br><hr size="1" width="90%"><i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Wed Jan 29 12:30:07 GMT+05:30 2014</i></body></html>"

Comment: You keep missing out the http:// at the beginning of the curl command - I assume you actually included it since you got a 404 response, which means that the job URL doesn't exist.  What is the URL of the job page if you look at it in the Jenkins UI ?